Sharepoint online hide certain groups from seeing 'Content Type' field on Edit Form
Is it possible to hide certain groups/user permissions from seeing the 'Content Type' field on Edit Form in sharepoint online. I still need to have the field for Admins but wanted to hide it from everyone else. I don't know how I can do this without using Power Apps/SPFx which I both can't use in this scenario.

Ok thanks, I guess I was looking more for a way just to hide it from staff.
In SharePoint 2013 we have a task list with 20+ content types (from SharePoint Designer task or collect data actions), when a user opens the task they don't see the content type and more importantly can't change it. In SPO, the same task list has been created, the content type is listed and can be changed by the user which would have a negative effect on the functionality of the Power Automate Flows linked. Do you have any suggestions on how to restrict, hide, etc the 'Content Type' field from staff so they don't accid

In the SharePoint, permissions have site, list/library, item/file level, it does not have column level.
So, there is no option to hide content type for certain groups/user permissions.
